# Windows 8.1 Video Player

Tags: html, windows-8, development-environment, winjs, windows-8.1

I'd like to know if (and how) I could show a video (youtube or dailymotion) in a Windows 8.1 App.

I want to watch from an url like : http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x1561xg

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solution for C#/XAML apps only. It might inspire you.

XAML

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" />
```

C#

```
webView.NavigateToString("<iframe width='620' height='348' src='http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x1561xg' frameborder='0'></iframe>");
```

Comment: Yes !

WinJS:
var webview = document.createElement("x-ms-webview");
var iframe = "<iframe id='player' type='text/html' width='400' height='300' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/x1561xg' frameborder='0'></iframe>";

webview.navigateToString(frame);